# What does navigator.app.exitApp() do..? Does it clear the entire app session...?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, winjs

On backbutton event I am exiting the app like this..

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
 if (app.history=="homepage"){
    navigator.app.exitApp();
 }
 else{
   WinJS.Navigation.back(1).done(function () { });
 }
}
```

Here I came out from my home page and again clicked on my app. Now it is starting from login page instead of home page..

What is the behaviour of navigator.app.exitApp()...?

Comment: it's hard to understand what did you mean without looking at your logging codes!

Answer (score 2):

If **by exiting you mean to come out of your application,** navigator.app.exitApp(); will help you to that.

However, this doesn't necessarily clear your application state or data. T**he application has just moved into background, and killing or pertaining it in the memory is all up to the OS.**

Terminating (exiting if you prefer) the application is not under the control of the application developer. It is completely managed by the OS (Android in this case). So, what you have is the normal behavior for apps under Mobile OS.

Comment: Does it mean.. we need to ask the user to re-login to the app even if he is not logged out...?

Comment: suppose I have 2 page. index.html and second.html. I'm in second.html and from this I executed ` navigator.app.exitApp();` From your answer it will go to the background, right? If I press the app icon again, will it bring me to second.html?

Comment: It does. However, if your underlying framework is rewired on the resume event, it may happen that you are landed on the landing (first) page.

Comment: @Indrasheker, you can probably save the session id in localstorage and everytime propagate the same on the server. It does requires some handling on the server too. Or else you can save username and passwords for auto logins.

Comment: @ AtanuCSE exactly when I click on the app it is starting from index.html page instead of second.html.

Comment: @TechMa9iac pause and resume is not  firing on backbutton event. And as you said If maintain the username and pwd, the application is itself restarting at that time everything in the session would be cleared..

Comment: @Indrasheker, pause will be fired on backbutton. resume will be fired when you launch your application if it's in background. And Even if your application closes, the values in the localstorage will persist.

Comment: I've used navigator.app.exitApp() and jquery mobile was my framework. JQM is not wired to any resume event. It always restart the app after using `navigator.app.exitApp()` AFAIK @Indrasheker you need to use some kind of checking in your homepage. Like you can maintain session with localstorage. At the login page you can check if the user is still logged in,if so send him to homapage, if not keep him in the login page. And once user logged in change the login status in local storage.

Comment: @TechMa9iac, as backbutton is itself an event, how to trigger pause event on click of backbutton..

Comment: @AtanuCSE, I have been using AngularJS, Ionic, OnsenUI and other Such frameworks for a while [I did used JQM before 2 years, long time]. And to keep it short and simple, navigator.app.exitApp is definitely not going to clear the session or state. Indrashekhar, no need to trigger pause or any such event. On click of back button, before you call navigator.app.exitApp, clear all variables referring your session. Save the username and password in loginstorage. next time the user opens the app, check if localstorage has username and password, and if yes, directly log them in.

Comment: @TechMa9iac as you said I will maintain the session with username and password and hope it helps me but app is launching along with the splash screen that would be a bit afraid thing.. any way let it be and I will your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.app.exitApp() closes/exits the App and the next time you click on the App icon, a new instance of the app is launched. So navigator.app.exitApp() doesn't simply puts the app in back ground or makes the app inactive but will terminate the app.

Comment: Terminating (exiting if you prefer) the application is not under the control of the application developer. It is completely managed by the OS (Android in this case).

Comment: @TechMa9iac, no, with navigator.app.exitApp() you exit and terminate the application. You can still see it on "recent", but that doesn't mean it isn't closed.